# Open new link in new tab from vb.net code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to open a link in a new tab from my vb.net code behind code.
This is my code.

```
Dim s As String = "window.open('" & url & "', '_blank', 'left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alertscript", s, True)
```

but this is opening a new popup window.
I want to open the url in a new tab of the same window.

Comment: on which event do you want to open, button click or something else

Comment: the above code is included in datagrid.selectedindexchanged fuction in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your script to

```
Dim s As String = "window.open('" & url & "', '_blank');"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alertscript", s, True)
```

You just need to use the `'_blank'` without `'left=100,top=100,resizable=yes'` if you want it to open in new tab.

The `'left=100,top=100,resizable=yes'` will create a new window with position `100px` from `top` and `left`